# Updating Symfony 1.4 with latest ICU I18N data

Tags: php, internationalization, symfony-1.4

I'm bugfixing a legacy [Symfony 1.4](http://symfony.com/legacy) project to be compliant with the latest ICU I18N data. Since 2010 there have been some changes to the list of countries in the world and related data like currencies.

I found [an article](http://symfony.com/blog/i18n-data-files-updated) and a [blog post](http://blog.hma-info.de/2009/01/27/prado-i18n-an-open-source-tale-with-happy-end/) by the author of Symfony with a script that should convert [ICU locale data-files](http://source.icu-project.org/repos/icu/icu/tags/latest/source/data/) to a format suited for Symfony. The instructions are there, but I'm having trouble to get the conversion script producing the output files. I'm not even sure what exact input files I have to use to make it work.

Is there anybody out there with any experience in converting ICU locale data to the Symfony 1.4 format?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the ICU format has some changes since last used by Fabien so you would have to modify his script.

As for which ICU input files to use you can check which files are actually read by the conversion script:

- data/misc/metaZones.txt
- all files from data/locales
- all files from data/curr
- all files from data/zone
- all files from data/lang
- all files from data/region

I've noticed one problem with running the script. You should change the line 126 from

```
$yml = str_replace('ExemplarCharacters:','ExemplarCharacters: |', $yml);
```

to

```
$yml = preg_replace('/ExemplarCharacters:\s*$/m', 'ExemplarCharacters: |', $yml);
```

As not all lines with `ExemplarCharacters:` key need the pipe at the end.

There have also been some changes made to the `metaZones.txt` file which you should take into consideration. I think what you need to do is to do the same research Fabien did some time ago: unserialize the `root.dat` file. The contents of the `metaZones.yml` was being post-processed and appended to this file (code from line 202). It seems that there is now some more info in this file and it's formatted differently which causes the conversion script to fail.

Comment: Thank you for your investigations in this matter! I will be working on this in the course of this week and will post my findings.

Comment: Your answer really helped me get started. Except for the `metaZones.txt` file, everything seems to parse now. So I'm awarding you the bounty even though there is still some work left to be done.

Comment: Glad I could help. If you manage to write a new script for importing the files maybe you will want to share with the guys who are still maintaining the Symfony 1.x version: https://github.com/LExpress/symfony1